# Why is vue + meteor tracker reactivity very slow for insert, but fast for remove in my code?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, vuejs2, latency, meteor-tracker

I'm starting out on an app using meteor, vue, and [vue-meteor-tracker](https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor-tracker). I have components whose content comes from a mongo collection. I think I've set up the pub / sub and reactivity correctly.

For some reason, it takes many seconds (sometimes as much as 15 seconds) for a newly inserted item to cause a redraw. On the other hand if I remove an item from the database, the redraw is instant.

My minimal code is here on [github](https://github.com/foobarbecue/thingbattle/tree/ebfc186985c209e5ee1ce32552207afa78d8d2ab) and the app is running for the time being at http://foobarbecue.com:3010

Comment: Did you try to use oplog tailing?

Comment: Hi Styx, I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I'm using the meteor development server, which I think relies on oplog tailing.

Comment: Why the close vote?